# Select first element if duplicate under order by statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-order-by

I want have the following query for SQL Server 2008:

```
SELECT * 
FROM INQUIRY_TABLE 
WHERE inquiryid >100 
  AND inquiryid < 200 
ORDER BY inquiryid ASC, actionNum ASC
```

But there may be duplicate `inquiryid` results. I only want the first (smallest `actionNum`) inquiry if `inquiryid` is a duplicate. How should I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Is the combination of actionNum and inquiryid unique? Are there any other columns on the table you need to return?

Comment: If the inquiryid is duplicate then actionNum has to be unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure it it will work with 2008 version, but you can use `top 1 with ties`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM INQUIRY_TABLE 
WHERE inquiryid >100 
and inquiryid < 200 
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY inquiryid ORDER BY actionNum)
```

While this is the simplest query, it will not necessarily preserve the order you specified in the question. If this order is important, then you better use Zaynul's answer (though I would prefer a cte over a derived table for readability).

Comment: I'm surprised the OP accepted this answer, given that it does not order the results as the question specifies.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I guess probably the order was not that important to the OP. I've suggested to use a different answer if the order was important...

Answer (score 3):

Grouping your records together on inquiryid should do the trick. You didn't specify the fields in this table but if you only want those two this query will work. If there are more fields than this that you wish to retrieve that are unique you should see the other answers for more in depth solutions.

```
SELECT inquiryid, MIN(actionNum)
FROM INQUIRY_TABLE 
WHERE inquiryid >100 
    and inquiryid < 200 
GROUP BY inquiryid
ORDER BY inquiryid asc, actionNum asc
```

Comment: This will work for OP question. If OP need more field then should use Zaynul aproach.

Comment: Good point, I edited my response to suggest the same. @JuanCarlosOropeza

Comment: It works but in my case since there are more than 40 fields in the table therefore if using group by there are other fields will complain

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY inquiryid ORDER BY actionNum) rn
     FROM 
         INQUIRY_TABLE 
     WHERE 
         inquiryid > 100 
         AND inquiryid < 200) t 
WHERE
    rn = 1
```

Or a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT 
    t1.* 
FROM
    INQUIRY_TABLE t1
WHERE
    actionNum = (SELECT MIN(actionNum) 
                 FROM INQUIRY_TABLE t2 
                 WHERE t1.inquiryid = t2.inquiryid)
    AND t1.inquiryid > 100 
    AND t1.inquiryid < 200
```